# App is rejecting due to 1.2 apple guidelines

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I developed an iOS application where in that application can rate and review other users in 3 sectors like:

1. Dating
2. Personal
3. Professional

The entire application was completed and built in 1.0, i have submitted the application to the app store but the application was rejected due to **1.2 guidelines**.

As per the 1.2 guidelines i have implemented

1. Block/Unblock
2. Terms & Condition
3. User Objection Features in 1.1 build

and resubmitted it to the app store but still rejected by the app store.

I'm getting issue from apple like this

> Your app still includes features that objectify real people, which
> could be interpreted as being offensive or mean-spirited.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please remove all offensive and mean-spirited content from your app
> and submit your revised binary for review.

Please see attached screenshots for examples of objectifying content.

[image: image posted by the asker]

can you point it out to me what is the mistake i am doing and should be revised?
Please help me on this Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Your app still includes features that objectify real people" is worrying since that seems to be the raison d'être of your app. Maybe you should consider *not* doing that :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks for respond so can i need to remove rating  to other user feature in my application or what?

Comment: **Dating Rating** and **Personal Rating** sound like _"features that objectify real people"_ to me. It seems like Apple want you to remove these features.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's guide lines, not programming.

Comment: @ZaEeMZaFaR & Sajida, did you found a solution ? I have the exact same problem. Thanks

Comment: Hello! Is anyone find a solution? I am facing a similar problem. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

What options do you present for taking the input on rating? May be the wordings you use are being considered offensive.

Taking user rating is not an offensive feature, you need to look into the next level of details which is causing rejection.

Comment: yes had have contacted apple..they said same as you.Thank you for your response.